# Do I need to establish a new connection between sandbox to sandbox

Tags: salesforce2salesforce

I have already established connection between two production orgs, now I want to share records from sandbox to sandbox, so how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to manually recreate the SF2SF connection everytime. So if you want to share between Sandboxes you have to set SF2SF up again. If you refresh a Sandbox you have to set it up again with a new connection.

Comment: But I'm unable to find Edit button on Salesforce to Salesforce setup page, with the help of that we can Enable for Salesforce to Salesforce.

Comment: You can't edit the existing connection when you refresh you have to create a new connection.